# Just a small integration question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Please don't solve it in whole, just help me out with the first step here. Why do I have $d/dx$ and $dt$ at the same time? How to reform the problem so it looks more familiar.

The way the problem is structured I find a bit odd. Thanks

$$\displaystyle \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_2^x\dfrac {dt}{t+ln(t)}\right)$$

Comment: Hint:  Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: FTC 2 only tells me the standard definite integration. What I am asking is how to make this problem looks more familar? Without x & t being combined.

Comment: This is phrased entirely in standard fashion.  Remember, the $t$ is just a dummy variable.  You can turn it into an $x$ if you prefer though some (including me) think it is very bad practice to use the same letter for both dummy and real variables in a single expression.

Comment: As to standard notation, I note that the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) uses exactly this form.  That is, they define $F(x)=\int_a^x f(f)\;dt$ and phrase the Theorem as $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is really asking whether or not you understand the statement of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Note that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is often phrased in two parts (and not all sources agree on which is "part 1" and which is "part 2").

Part 1 is often stated: Suppose $f(x)$ is an integrable function. Then
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t) dt = f(x).$$
Part 2 is often stated: Suppose $f(x)$ is an integrable function and that $F(x)$ is a function such that $F'(x) = f(x)$. Then
$$ \int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b) - F(a).$$

---

I will also comment on some confusion in the problem. The $dt$ within the integrand serves to indicate what variable is being integrated. In this case, it's the $t$ variable. But the integral is a function of $x$. That is, there is a function in your question that we might call $g(x)$, given by
$$ g(x) = \int_2^x \frac{dt}{t + \ln t}.$$
This function has the interpretation "give the area under the graph of the function $1/(t + \ln t)$ from $2$ to $x$". So the $x$ and the $t$ are playing different roles: $t$ is what is being integrated, while $x$ is the variable of the overall function.

It would be very confusing to write
$$ \frac{d}{d{\color{#dd1111} x}} \int_2^{\color{#dd1111}x} \frac{d{\color{#5555ff} x}}{{\color{#5555ff}x} + \ln {\color{#5555ff} x}},$$
as the red $\color{#dd1111}x$ and the blue $\color{#5555ff}x$ have different meanings.

If it is helpful, I wrote a [short note on introductory calculus](http://davidlowryduda.com/an-intuitive-introduction-to-calculus/) for my students a few years ago.